# Python - Turn dictionary into hierarchical tree like structure to be displayed in tkinter

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I have a dictionary in the form:

```
{
"filename":"file.txt",
"filesize":"500kb",
"maxcolwidth":{
    "col1":"300",
    "col2":"2",
    "col3":"3"},
"numberofcolumns":"3",
"datatypes":{
    "col1":"string",
    "col2":"int",
    "col3":"int"},
"rowcount":"400"
}
```

I'm currently using Tkinter for python to build a GUI, but cannot find an easy/elegant way of displaying the following dictionary in either a tkinter treeview widget or a nicely formatted string to display in a text box. The output i was looking for was something like this:

```
Filename - file.txt
Filesize - 500KB
Maxcolwidth - col1 - 300
              col2 - 2
              col3 - 3
Numberofcolumns - 3
Datatypes - col1 - string
            col2 - int
            col3 - int
rowcount -  400
```

or more like a hierarchical tree

```
Filename
    file.txt
Filesize
    500KB
Maxcolwidth
    col1
        300
    col2
        2
    col3
        3
Numberofcolumns
    3
Datatypes
    col1
        string
    col2
        int
    col3
        int
rowcount
    400
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) First decide and describe what you want to achieve. 2) Then try to code it. 3) If you are stuck, post what you wrote.

Comment: You say you cannot find an easy or elegant way to use Treeview. Can you show us the "uneasy" or "unelegant" way that you've tried so we don't make suggestions that you've already dismissed?

Comment: @EricLevieil Well i would prefer to have a treeview widget with the expandable nodes but cant get my scenario to work with the examples shown in the tkinter api documentation.

Comment: @BryanOakley I dont actually have an elegant/uneasy way of doing it, i have tried little snippets of code from the tkinter api documentation for the tkk treeview widget but cant get it to work. any suggestions would be welcome as i havent got a working version yet so anything you suggest would help, thanks

Comment: If you use correctly the examples given at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html and http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html, especially the insert method and its parent argument, it should work. You should probably use recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create a treeview with one additional column, and then add a function that adds an item to the tree. It adds an item, and if the value is a dictionary, it recurses through all of the child elements.

Here's a simple example using python 2.x. For python 3.x you only have to change the imports. I don't know if it meets your definition of "elegant" or "easy".

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

DATA = {
    "filename":"file.txt",
    "filesize":"500kb",
    "maxcolwidth": {
        "col1":"300",
        "col2":"2",
        "col3":"3"
        },
    "numberofcolumns":"3",
    "datatypes": {
        "col1":"string",
        "col2":"int",
        "col3":"int"
        },
    "rowcount":"400"
    }

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=("value",))
        self.vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.tree.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.addNode(value=DATA, parentNode="")

    def addNode(self, value, parentNode="", key=None):
        if key is None:
            id = ""
        else:
            id = self.tree.insert(parentNode, "end", text=key)

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            self.tree.item(id, open=True)
            for (key, value) in value.iteritems():
                self.addNode(value, id, key)
        else:
            self.tree.item(id, values=(value,))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```